# Where does Visual Studio 2013 save test dlls and other temp files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I run tests from Visual Studio 2013, but its results fill my hard drive!

Where I can find these temp files and delete them?

Comment: what kind of tests? Coded UI tests? or others? check in your project directory on disk...

Comment: search for folder `TestResults`

Comment: Yes,I find TestResults near my Solution file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @thumbmunkeys said: You need to look at Solution folder. And search for Folder `TestResults`.